# kcfstreamerrordomainssl, -9813 on IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ssl, tls1.2

ERROR :  nsurlconnection/cfurlconnection http load failed (kcfstreamerrordomainssl, -9813)

subdomain : https://staging.vtavalet.com:3000

I am trying to build ios App using above subdomain url on ios9 but getting above error.  I have did all possible things like arbitrary loads set to TRUE enabled TLSv1.2 also.But still facing the same error.

Can you provide me better solution on this how to resolve this -9813 code which coming in Error.